# Can I implement a PK Type argument for a generic repository?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, repository, primary-key

I'm trying to implement a generic repository for my base class of `DbEntity` - the ID of which may be an `int` or a `guid`.

I almost have it working, but I am stuck on the repository's `SelectByID()` method.

The syntax `table.Find(id)` works just fine.

But the syntax `SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id)` does not.  It gives me `operator '=='cannot be applied to operants of type PKT and PKT`

*But I want to use the second version (because it allows me to load related entities with `Include()`.)*

I have tried using no constraint for PKT.
I have tried using a `struct` constraint but I still get the same error.

How should I be implementing this?

**Update**

After a lot of help from @StriplingWarrior, here is what I have come up with:

```
public virtual T SelectByID(PKT id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
    if (includeExpressions.Any())
    {
        var set = includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                    (table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty("ID");
        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, propertyInfo);
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(id, typeof(PKT));
        BinaryExpression binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, constantExpression);
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameter);

        return set.SingleOrDefault(lambda);

    }
    return table.Find(id);
}
```

---

**Base Entities**

```
    public interface IDBEntity<PKT>
        where PKT : struct
    {
        PKT ID { get; set; }
        string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class DBEntity<PKT> : IDBEntity<PKT>
        where PKT : struct 
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public PKT ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
    public class Car : DBEntity<Guid>
    {
        public string Colour { get; set; }
    }
    public class Pet : DBEntity<int>
    {
        public bool FurryOrNot { get; set; }
    }
```

**Generic Repository**

```
    public class GenericRepository<T, PKT> : IGenericRepository<T, PKT>
        where T : DBEntity<PKT>
        where PKT : struct
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = null;
        private DbSet<T> table = null;


        public GenericRepository()
        {
            db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            table = db.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual T SelectByID(PKT id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {
            if (includeExpressions.Any())
            {
                var set = includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                         (table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

                return set.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);

            }
            return table.Find(id);
        }


        public virtual IQueryable<T> AllAsQueryable(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {
            return includeExpressions.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                (table, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
        }



        public virtual IQueryable<T> AllWhereAsQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> wherePredicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)
        {
            return AllAsQueryable(includeExpressions).Where(wherePredicate);
        }


        public virtual void Create(T obj)
        {
            table.Add(obj);
            Save();
        }



        public virtual void Edit(T obj)
        {
            table.Attach(obj);
            db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
        }



        public void Delete(object id)
        {
            T existing = table.Find(id);
            table.Remove(existing);
            Save();
        }



        public virtual void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }



        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're running into this error is because at compile time the `==` operator is trying to get bound based on the information known about the classes at compile-time, which isn't much.

You may want to try using `.Equals()` instead. I'm not sure whether that will work.

The way that I've gone about this in the past is by generating an expression tree at run-time that uses the actual known run-time type of the generic parameter. So rather than this:

```
return set.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

... it would be something like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter("s", typeof(T));
return set.SingleOrDefault(
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            /*make an expression that gets the ID property from parameter*/,
            Expression.Constant(id, typeof(PKT)),
        parameter));
```

Comment: `generating an expression tree at run-time that uses the actual known run-time type of the generic parameter`. Cool, thank you. I might struggle to get that right... is there a psuedo / example you could add that would point me in the right direction?

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox: Yeah, I was working on adding to my answer. I've added some code that should get you headed in the right direction. If you look at [`Expression.MakeMemberAccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.makememberaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) that should help you get the rest of the way there.

Comment: Thanks a million, much appreciated :)